# How to make the height of a custom picker responsive?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, responsive

I have a problem with the height of my custom picker when the user select a bigger font for his device (Android), the font is relative but his height no.

With in XAML HeightRequest setted to 40 and in the renderer Control.SetMinimumHeight (30); and default resolution:

[image: default resolution example]

When the user select the highest resolution:

[image: Highest resolution example]

I was thinking that using MinimumHeight will be useful but not. If I remove the heighRequest in XAML and

```
//in custom renderer
Control.SetMinimumHeight(30);
Control.SetHeight(30);
```

I get a responsive "box" but bigger than what I want.

[image: bigger box]

EDIT

I just discover a part of the problem, sometime the text is longer and needs two rows, in custom render i found this two lines:

```
Control.SetMaxLines(2);
Control.SetLines(2);
```

If I remove the SetLines I get a responsive height but it is like for one line, the text of second one is cutted...

Comment: maybe you could nest a gride outside,and set the <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>